# Add extra class with product category IDs on WooCommerce archives pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I want to add a custom class to the categories on the product archive page so that I can add custom styles to the categories tags.

Example:

- Product X in Category 1 --> Category Tag in Yellow
- Product Y in Category 2 --> Category Tag in Red

I'm using this php snippet, but this is for single product pages and is applied to the `<body>` element. How can I change it to work for shop archive pages as well?

```php
add_filter( 'body_class','my_body_classes2' );
function my_body_classes2( $classes ) {

    if ( is_product() ) {

        global $post;
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
            $classes[] = 'product-in-cat-' . $product_cat_id;    
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the newer `woocommerce_post_class` filter hook

So you get:

```php
/**
 * WooCommerce Post Class filter.
 *
 * @since 3.6.2
 * @param array      $classes Array of CSS classes.
 * @param WC_Product $product Product object.
 */
function filter_woocommerce_post_class( $classes, $product ) {  
    // Returns true when viewing a product category archive.
    // Returns true when on the product archive page (shop).
    if ( is_product_category() || is_shop() ) {
        // Set taxonmy
        $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
        
        // Get the terms
        $terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), $taxonomy );
        
        // Error or empty
        if ( is_wp_error( $terms ) || empty( $terms ) ) {
            return $classes;
        }
        
        // Loop trough
        foreach ( $terms as $index => $term ) {
            // Product term Id
            $term_id = $term->term_id;
            
            // Add new class
            $classes[] = 'product-in-cat-' . $term_id;
        }
    }
    
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_post_class', 'filter_woocommerce_post_class', 10, 2 );
```

---

**Note:** the if condition can be extended/constrained with other [conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/)

Example:

- `is_product()` - Returns true on a single product page. Wrapper for is_singular.
- etc..

> To NOT apply this, use `!` in the if condition:
>
> ```php
> // NOT
> if ( ! is_product_category() )..
> ```